Не работает стабильно ftp у провайдера. Как выявить причину и помочь провайдеру найти косяк?
Сижу на Ро****еком. Подключаюсь к серверу через ftp успешно. Открываю 1-2 папки, иногда 3 всё ок, потом зависает. Проверял в 3х ftp клиентах. Пасивный режим. До этого 6 лет всё было ок. Не может прочитать папки, файлы не важно. Не работают ftp всех хостингов.
Зависает на команадах MLSD или PASV
Как только меняю инет на ноуте на мобильный, к примеру билайн (раздаю wifi с телефона), то ftp уже работает без единого косяка.
Как рост****ому указать на косяк и тыкнуть где именно он. Если сканировать типа telnet то ошибки нет, т.к. при подключении к серверу ошибки нет. Менял IP и проверял даже не андройде. Всё тоже самое.

DNS менял в роутере.

Переходи на sftp или ftps

Роутер ростелекомовский? Если кабель провайдера напрямую в компьютер воткнуть?
